# XCode 12 - Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, babeljs

Edit: Just created a brand new project, (npx react-native-init), still the same exact issue. No clue what's happening, never had this issue before.

App is building / running file locally. It's only when I archive this issue pops up.

Tried:

- Deleting pod file / workspace
- Checking 'For install builds only'
- Disable / Enable the 'login' in 'Keychain Access'
- Cleaning and restarting computer
- Archiving in debug and release

Node: 14.16.1 / RN: 0.64.0 / Typescript

What else should I do? Really stuck here. It doesn't make sense it builds fine locally but not in Archive. Thank you.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/andrewyoung/tacapp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/doctor/doctor.js:28:21)
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: @BurakAkkaş Yes, this is default what I tried. I just wanted to add that archiving in debug mode also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Got it - Per [this article](https://msirius.medium.com/the-resurrection-of-a-year-old-react-native-app-2347de873c0f) I used: nvm unalias default and my app is now running.

Comment: Thanks. I made it work by doing this:

`brew install nvm` and then `nvm unalias default`

And then build again for my device

Comment: I fixed it by using the command `nvm alias default v16.18.0` (You can check the versions with 'nvm ls' and choose one)